# I would like to enter a future date in a cell and when it reaches that date the cell goes blank

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a on call sheet, in column f it is a "do not call until further notice". I would like to be able to put a future date in that cell and when that comes it clears the contents in that cell. I am using a filter function and when it looks at the do not call column it is looking for a blank cell to move the info to the proper sheet. Everything works great accept trying to get the date to disappear thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to enter a future date in a cell and when it reaches that date the cell goes blank

```
=IF(TODAY()="12/12/2033"; "12/12/2033"; )
```

Comment: Wont this formula get deleted if I put this in the cell where the date will be entered in the cell. If I have a "Do not call until" column and I add a date that is 6/5/2022, I would like to be able to have that cell go blank when 6/5/2022 is here

Comment: @kevinc1973 with this formula the date needs to be hardcoded into formula. also, not sure if you are interested, but you can have a date and when that date reaches a specific day you can use conditional formatting to "hide" that date

Comment: I dont think that will work I cant have people changing the formula I was hoping for a code to run instead if there is one, but thank you